# countries to travel using albanian residence permit

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, albania

I have an Albanian residence permit. Can i travel to Schengen countries without visa. If not, is it easy to get a Schengen visa? Also, how can I get an Albanian passport?

Answer (score 1):

Albanian residence permits don't let you travel anywhere where you would otherwise need a visa.

As for how to become an Albanian citizen, the requirements are summarised [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_nationality_law#Naturalisation)